# Understand the tensor product over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

I often use the tensor product but I don't understand it very well despite that I know his universal property and an example of his construction, for me it is like a black box and I would like to understand it better. For example, if we consider the tensor product of 2 algebras over a field, $A \otimes_{K} B$, and if $a \in A, b \in B$, what does it imply that $a \otimes b = 0$ ?

Does someone has a good reference (a section of a book, or just lecture notes) to see more clearly what is $A \otimes_{K} B$ ?

Thank you

Comment: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf

Comment: In your specific case $a\otimes b=0$ surely implies that either $a=0$ or $b=0$. This is because the tensor product is over *a field*. If $a=\sum_i a_ie_i$, $b=\sum_j b_jf_j$ where the $e_i$s (resp. $f_j$s) are elements of some $K$-basis of $A$ (resp. $B$), then the tensor products $e_i\otimes f_j$ are linearly independent etc.

Comment: Over the years it has helped me a lot to use the example of $A=B=K[x]$ of two polynomial rings, when $A\otimes_KB$ is naturally isomorphic to $K[x,y]$. Also, if $A=K[x]$ and $B$ is an extension field, then $A\otimes_KB\simeq B[x]$. If both are simple extension fields, then that together with flatness gives a lot.

Comment: When non-commutative algebras appear, it becomes hairier :-)

Comment: Thank you, I think that you are right but how do you prove rigorously that the tensor products $e_i \otimes f_j$ are linearly independent ? I understand the idea, we do just linear combinations over $K$, so it will not affect the linear independence, but I don't see how prove it.